# No file access permissions when using Ivy

Tags: ivy

I'm using ivy to download dependencies, but the build process failed, and the error infomation showing below:

```
/workspace/jenkins/workspace/XXXModule/src/build/build-ivy.xml:86: impossible to resolve dependencies:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /homes/babel/.ivy2/cache/resolved-xxx-xxx-caller-working.xml (The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.)
```

It seems I have no permissions to access the caller-working.xml in the cache directory.(The script is running on an IC Server, so maybe I actually not have the permission). But I want to know why Ivy need to access that file, what is the file used to do? What permission do I need?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is caused by a mismatch between the local user UID and the UID on the remote file server.

I highly suggest that you use a local cache and not share it across the network. The cache is exactly that, a local copy of previously downloaded files, it is not a repository.